# Find objects that share the same array value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have the following array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5ffcab3a065d103265f92bfc",
        "label": "Test Group 1",
        "channels": [
            "44332"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "5f85362e573c400e91bb7b15",
        "label": "Test Group 2",
        "channels": [
            "85705",
            "87984"
        ]
    }
]
```

I am trying to relate objects by their `channels` values. If two objects share the same value in their `channels` array, I would like their ids to be output.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: i would expect the id of both object if there is common channel between them

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far and where you're stuck?

Comment: @eol i tried using nested for loop.. but i am trying to look if there is better way

Comment: What if object 1 has a channel in common with object 2, and object 2 has a channel in common with object 3, but object 1 has no common channel with object 3, what should be the output? What if object 1 also has a common channel with object 3, what should be the output? This needs some clarification...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all we note that this relation (of sharing a common channel) is not transitive:

if A relates to B and B relates to C, it does not follow that A relates to C.

The relation is however commutative:

if A relates to B, then B relates to A.

So, a possible useful output could be a list of *sorted pairs* of ids. We cannot hope to group them into larger groups, as then the lack of transitivity poses problems.

In order to extract these pairs, you could first group ids per channel, i.e. for each channel you would have a list of ids.

Then the solution consists of each possible sorted pair you can take from the *same* list. I say sorted, because reversed pairs do not give additional information, due to the commutative nature of the relation, so these can be excluded.

Duplicate pairs should be removed from the result.

For this we can make use of Maps and Sets:

```js
// Some example data
let data = [
    { id: "a", channels: [1, 2, 3] },
    { id: "b", channels: [2, 4, 6] },
    { id: "c", channels: [3, 6, 9] },
    { id: "d", channels: [4, 8, 12] },
    { id: "e", channels: [5, 10, 15] },
]

// Get the object ids grouped per channel
let temp = data.flatMap(({id, channels}) => channels.map(channel => [channel, id]));
let map = new Map(temp.map(([channel]) => [channel, []]));
for (let [channel, id] of temp) map.get(channel).push(id);
// Create unique pairs of connected ids
let set = new Set(Array.from(map.values(), ids =>
    ids.map(id =>
         ids.map(id2 => id < id2 && JSON.stringify([id, id2]))
    )
).flat(2).filter(Boolean));
// Extract result
let result = Array.from(set, JSON.parse);

console.log(result);
```